# Rails: Filter on has_many_through association where all checked associations exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to build a checkbox filter, which further reduces the number of results with each extra checked box, where each checkbox represents a relation in a has_many through association.

I have an app with the following models:

- Hospital
- HospitalFeatures
- Features

Here are the associations:

```
class Hospital < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hospital_features
  has_many :features, through: :hospital_features
end

class HospitalFeature < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hospital
  belongs_to :feature
end

class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hospital_features
  has_many :hospitals, through: :hospital_features
end
```

I have a check-box form that lists all of the features available.

```
<%= label_tag("helipad", "Helipad") %>
<%= check_box_tag("features[]", "helipad" %>

<%= label_tag("telesurgery", "Telesurgery") %>
<%= check_box_tag("features[]", "telesurgery" %>

<%= label_tag("emergency room", "Emergency Room") %>
<%= check_box_tag("features[]", "emergency room" %>
```

I am trying to filter like you would on a shopping site, where each checked box further filters to only the hospitals with the ALL checked features.

The query I'm using now:

```
hospitals = Hospital.joins(:features).where(features: {name: features} )
```

does the opposite. Each extra box checked increases the number of results since it returns hospitals with ANY one of the checked features, rather than the hospitals with ALL of the checked features.

So if you check "helipad" and "telesurgery", it should return only hospitals with both "helipad" AND "telesurgery" rather than any hospital with either "helipad" OR "telesurgery".

Looked around and can't seem to find an obvious solution. I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is not the most beautiful solution, but it worked for me.

```
Hospital.joins(:features).where(features: {name: features}).group('hospitals.id').having("count(*) >= ?", features.size)
```

Comment: I think that the issue with this method is that I have no problem adding an AND condition with dot notation. I can do that by simply adding another `where`.

The problem being I don't know in advance how many boxes will be checked, so I don't know how many `where`s to include. If there is a way to dynamically add an arbitrary number of `where`s, that would be a valid solution.

Comment: Sorry, I take that back.

This AR: `Hospital.joins(:features).where(, 3).where("feature_id = ?", 4)`

Produces this SQL: 
`SELECT "hospitals".* FROM "hospitals" INNER JOIN "hospital_features" ON "hospital_features"."hospital_id" = "hospitals"."id" INNER JOIN "features" ON "features"."id" = "hospital_features"."feature_id" WHERE (feature_id = 3) AND (feature_id = 4)`

That's clearly wrong as it would require one row to have 2 distinct feature_ids, which is impossible. I'm lost again.

Comment: Second attempt. You should put this in another answer so I'd see the change.

This ended up very similar to the solution I ended up using which was:

  hospitals = Hospital.joins(:features)
    .where('features.name in (?)', searched_features)
    .group("hospitals.id")
    .having('COUNT(*) = ?', searched_features.length)

This returns the same hospital for each feature that that hospital has. So if the list contains 4 features, and a hospital has all 4, that hospital will be returned 4 times.
So then you group by hospital id and add 'HAVING COUNT(*)' equal to the number of filtered features.

Answer (score 1):

Got a solution. First joined hospitals to features then filtered where 'features.name in (?)' interpolating the features array into the query.

So this will return the same hospital for each feature that that hospital has.  So if the list contains 4 features, and a hospital has all 4, that hospital will be returned 4 times. Likewise, if it only had 3 of the 4 features, it would return it 3 times.

So then you group by hospital id and add 'HAVING COUNT(*)' equal to the number of filtered features.

Then end result being:

```
  hospitals = Hospital.joins(:features)
    .where('features.name in (?)', searched_features)
    .group("hospitals.id")
    .having('COUNT(*) = ?', searched_features.length)
```

Hope this help someone else eventually. Let me know if anyone finds a more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a lot of options for doing this -- one that's worked well for me is Sunspot Solr filtering with facets. Railscasts explains it pretty well: http://railscasts.com/episodes/278-search-with-sunspot.

Answer (score 0):

Using my [Where Exists](https://github.com/EugZol/where_exists) gem:

```
result = Hospital.all
features.each do |feature|
  result = scope.where_exists(:features, name: feature)
end
```